# UITableview section color

Tags: swift, uitableview

Does it possible to set background color for each section in UITableView separately, not for the whole UITableView?

I need section background, not cells itself. I need solid background UNDER the cells.

I have some cells with white background but it looks not nice when batchupdates is animating changes, tiny gaps appear between some cells, and transparency on swipe. At the same time, I have a section that have transparent cells, so background for the whole tableView does not work here.

Comment: You can try setting the background color in cellForRow method according to the particular section.

Comment: PGDev Thanks, I did that in the first seconds to emulate section BG. But wanted to get BG under the cells to get more perfect animations. So that's not what I am looking for...

Answer (score -1):

Using

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       if indexPath.section == 0 {
          // set Background
       }
    }
```

Comment: I need section background, not cells itself. I need background UNDER the cells.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        if let headerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
            headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = .white // This is Background colour for section
            headerView.textLabel?.textColor = .black // This is color of Text
        }
    }
```

Comment: You showed how to change background color on section HEADED, not of the section. It will not change background under the cells in section as I know, isn't it?